# Encriptar datos enviados por url

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy enviando un **id** por url a la pagina index.php que carga ciertos datos respectivamente del **id** que obtuvo a traves una variables de sesion, el detalle es que si el **usuario 1 con id 1** cambia el **id 1 por id 2** en la url consultaria datos que no le corresponden, por eso quiero encriptar un poco el id que se muestra en la url.

```
function(){
        var id_e=document.getElementById('input').value;
        window.location.href='http://localhost/index.php?id_e='+id_e;
        return;

    }
```

Comment: No se entiende bien lo que necesitas. ¿El ID es confidencial? ¿Es confidencial el resultado que se obtiene al visitar la url adonde estás redirigiendo? ¿No bastaría con proteger index.php con un diálogo de autenticación?

Comment: El resultado que se obtiene al visitar index.php es generado atravez del id que se envia por url, el cual debe ser unico y privado, si el usuario x entra y cambia en la url el id puede consultar datos agenos a su id...

Comment: No se entiende bien. ¿Por qué el id lo tienes en un input pero sin embargo lo quieres encriptar?. ¿Estás seguro que eso es lo que quieres?

Comment: Es tan facil como ver el id recibido y compararlo con el id de session del usuario actual, si son iguales puede ver los datos. podra enviar 1 2 3 4 5  el que sea pero como id_session no es igual al id recibido no lo dejara pasar saludos!

Comment: Si vas a recibir el id en un php, ¿por qué no lo envías por POST?. De esta forma no se mostrará en la url. ¿o no puedes cambiar el formulario?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Por lo que entiendo, quieres impedir que un usuario, manipulando la url (cuyo parámetro es un id numérico) pueda ver datos de otro usuario.

**Si el id_e se genera en el backend**

En el código que nos mostraste no queda claro de donde proviene el parámetro `id_e`, pero suponiendo que está generado en el backend, y se pasa al browser en tiempo de ejecución (derechamente con PHP o por ajax), entonces hay dos flujos posibles.

En un flujo, el más tradicional, tienes una tabla de tokens, en la cual existe el campo `id_e` y el campo `hash`. En vez de pasarle directamente el `id_e` al browser, le pasas el hash.

```
function(){
    var hash=document.getElementById('input').value;
    window.location.href='http://localhost/index.php?hash='+hash;
    return;
}
```

El usuario eventualmente visitará una url que en vez de un id numérico tiene un hash, y cuando recibes la petición a `index.php`, realizas una búsqueda en tu tabla de tokens para ver a qué `id_e` corresponde el hash que te mandaron.

```
<?php

  $hash = $_GET['hash'];
  $id_e = buscar_en_tabla_de_tokens($hash);
```

La generación del hash se puede hacer de muchas maneras. En el fondo es un string alfanumérico al azar que podría componerse, por ejemplo, del resultado de hashear el id:

```
$hash = password_hash($id_e, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

Lo importante es que sólo el lado del servidor sepa con qué algoritmo estás encriptando y qué le pasas a ese algoritmo.

Hay una segunda manera que son los [json Web Tokens](https://jwt.io/), que no requiere utilizar una tabla de tokens, sino que ocurre entre el browser y el código del backend. Sin embargo, esa manera requiere que envíes una petición con headers y payload, lo cual no vas a poder hacer usando  `window.location.href`

Significa que en el mejor de los casos, tendrás que crear tu tabla de tokens y añadir la lógica para consultar esa tabla para saber el id_e

**Si el id_e se genera en el browser**

Si el `id_e` se genera enteramente del lado del cliente, cualquier encriptación que le pongas va a poder revertirse simplemente mirando el código js del frontend. En ese caso no hay mucho que hacer salvo oscurecer un poco el ID, por ejemplo usando base64.

```
function(){
    var id_e=document.getElementById('input').value;
    id_e = window.btoa(id_e);
    window.location.href='http://localhost/index.php?id_e='+id_e;
    return;
}
```

y luego en `index.php`

```
<?php
  $id_e = base64decode($_GET['id']);
```

Pero repito, eso no es seguridad sino simplemente oscurecimiento. Cualquiera que vea tu código js sabrá cómo generar el `id_e` de otros valores numéricos.

Comment: Gracias @amenadiel, la informacion esta muy completa y detallada.

Answer (score 0):

Yo tengo la misma duda uso el function asi

```
function mostrarnoticia (id){
    window.location.href='noticiacompleta.php?noticias='+id;
}
```

Y el id lo capturo de un href de una tabla de esta manera

```
<a href="" data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#myModal" id="<?php echo $row['noticias_id']; ?>" >
```

Entonces mi url sale

> http://localhost/musica/noticiacompleta.php?noticias=2

Comment: estas respondiendo a la pregunta o estas haciendo otra pregunta?